# 'Header already sent' Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, plugins

I am trying to make a simple plugin that welcomes users when they visit the site for the first time but I keep getting a 'headers already sent' error.

I know this error has something to do with the cookie not being sent in the header. And I already found some solutions but none that work within the plugin. Can I do all this inside the plugin ? 
(I'm trying to write this inside a wordpress widget)

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
  setcookie ('visited', 'yes', time() + 3600);      
  echo "Welcome.";
}
else{                                               
  echo "Welcome back";
}
```

So if a user visits the site for the first time I want him to see 'Welcome' but if he is a returning visitor, I want to display 'welcome back',

Comment: Since cookies are sent in the response header, and headers are sent _before_ any output, you need to set the cookie before any output as well.

Comment: You could set the cookie in JS and then read it using PHP. If it doesn't exist, it's a new user and if it exists, it's a returning user. You could also move the code to somewhere, before any output (and store the greeting string in a variable to be used later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use return instead of echo  so the response is manage by the plugin

```
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
      setcookie ('visited', 'yes', time() + 3600);      
      return  "Welcome.";
    }
    else{                                               
      return  "Welcome back";
    }
```